# Windows Azure TableServiceContext UndoChanges

Tags: windows, azure-storage

When trying to save an object using an illegal character (e.g. '/') in the RowKey an exception is thrown when calling

```
_tableServiceContext.AddObject(tableName, myEntity);
```

I get an System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException with the info "out of range", which is easily prevented (by preventing or checking for illegal characters).

My question now is, how do I recover from this status? After such an error all succeeding AddObject calls fail, presumably because the "corrupt object" still belong to the context.

Therefore I'm looking for a "UndoChanges" possibility.

Any hints are appreciated, thanks.

P.S.:
I'm looking for a better way than to throw away the context or to delete the object from the context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to detach the entity from the context. If that's not an option for some reason, you could retry the save with `SaveChangesOption.ContinueOnErrors` set. eg,

```
_tableServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.ContinueOnError);
```

This basically applies all the updates one at a time, instead of in batches. Note it will ignore all errors that occur, not just the one from the illegal entity.

Comment: Detaching the entity from the context is accomplishing what I need, thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Oh, good then. I thought that wasn't an option, since you didn't want to "delete the object from the context".